# Поменять wicd на network-manager-gnome

Tags: linux, сеть, debian, network-manager

Вообщем то проблема такая. Нужно поменять стандартный wicd на гномовский network-manager.
Debian 10 x64 lxde. Пробовал `apt install network-manager` и `apt install network-manager-gnome`. Все установилось, потом,
`systemctl enable network-manager`

`systemctl stop wicd`

`systemctl disable wicd`
Но при перезегрузке снова включается wicd. Пробовал его совсем удалить но все ровно почему то сеть идет через него, а network-manager пишет нет подключения. Кто знает как это все правильно настроить. Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так - он не будет запускаться даже вручную

```
systemctl mask wicd
```

Значек на панеле всёравно может появиться. Тут проще удалить wicd полностью, если не найдешь параметр в автозапуске.

Значек для нетворк менеджера

```
nm-applet
```